# *just using min-width* hide a div element

Tags: css, media-queries

***just using min-width*** I would like to hide `challange-target` element below 408px and show  the  `challange-target` up to `408px`.

I tried this code but it does not work:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 408px) {
    .challange-target {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yyQ5u/31/)

Answer (score 4):

You mean you want to hide `.challenge-target` when screen width < 408, and show it at 408px when screen width is >= 408px?

smallest first; hide that elem

```
.challange-target {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 408px) {
    .challange-target {
        display: block;
        width:408px;
    }
}
```